# Can neural cryptanalysis be applied to AES?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, des, rijndael

In [this Wikipedia article about Neural cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_cryptography#Applications) (section applications) it states:

> In 1995, Sebastien Dourlens applied neural networks to cryptanalyze DES by allowing the networks to learn how to invert the S-tables of the DES. The bias in DES studied through Differential Cryptanalysis by Adi Shamir is highlighted. The experiment shows about 50% of the key bits can be found, allowing the complete key to be found in a short time.

It could very well be that I misunderstood something, but I think that the same "attack" can't be used for AES, since the [Inverse Rijndael S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Inverse_S-box) is public knowledge or am I wrong? Is AES designed this way to prevent an attack by inverting the S-box?

Comment: The inverse S-box is useless if you don't have the key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any practical uses for machine learning for cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9751/29554)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**No. Neuro-Cryptanalysis fails on serious ciphers**, including DES and AES.

Sebastien Dourlens's *Neuro-differential cryptanalysis of DES* (in sections 5.4.2 and 5.4.3 of his [1996 mémoire](https://fr.scribd.com/document/245458980/Applied-Neuro-Cryptography)) learns an S-box. Applied to Unix crypt (section 5.4.4), it memorizes passwords/hash pairs (by a training requiring "from several days to several years") and then merely performs a quick retrieval; something a hash table does routinely and quickly! Neither is relevant to cryptanalysis.

Mohammed M. Alani's *Neuro-Cryptanalysis of DES and Triple-DES* (in [proceedings of ICONIP 2012](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-34500-5_75)) claims cryptanalysis of DES or 3DES from 2048 or 4096 examples in an hour of Matlab on a standard PC; but there is no indication that it recovers the key or is  otherwise capable of predicting more input/output mappings than supplied in training (even though the later is a stated objective). My guess is that - at best - it performs similar plaintext/ciphertext memorization thru training.

---

Update: The above remains true, despite recent and noteworthy progress in the field of neuro cryptanalysis of weakened ciphers, with Aron Gohr's [*Improving Attacks on Round-Reduced Speck32/64 using Deep Learning*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/037), in [proceedings of Crypto 2019](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-26951-7_6). It's further analysed by Adrien Benamira, David Gerault, Thomas Peyrin and Quan Quan Tan in [*A Deeper Look at Machine Learning-Based Cryptanalysis*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/287) (eprint, March 2021).

Comment: I think its important to note, that Neuro-Cryptanalysis has failed **so far** on serious ciphers.

Comment: @Dylan: Neuro-Cryptanalysis as in these papers (thus as in the question) examines the cipher as a black box, without a description of its internals. That's dooms such Neuro-Cryptanalysis, putting it at a tremendous disadvantage compared to traditional cryptanalysis, and automated cryptanalysis crunching a description of the cipher (e.g. encoded as a [satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem of applied machine learning techniques on serious ciphers is that you don't have some good property like continuity which tells you when you are too far, a bit far or close to your solution. Take a look of this polynomial curve over a finite, How do you get the order of this polynomial based on the shape of this graph?
[image]

By the way, block ciphers like AES are very indistinguishable from random functions. Therefore, they leak almost no information. I think that in order to train any type of neural network architecture, you would require an enormous amount of input and output data to model a pseudo-random construction. It is practically as expensive as a brute force attack.

Comment: re. _"block ciphers like AES are very indistinguishable from true random functions. "_  Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Well, what I really mean is that AES is a very good CSPRF(Very computably indistinguishable from something truly random) – 
and you can check it in the NISTIR 6390 https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=151193

I'm sorry if my comment is misleading