# Machine Learning to improve Encryption algorithms

Tags: encryption, machine-learning

Can machine learning be used to improve encryption algorithms e.g.image encryption algorithms that use ECC ?

Answer (score 2):

**No**. There is large consensus that:

- There is nothing special about image encryption algorithm, they are just encryption algorithms.
- ECC is useful for such algorithms inasmuch as they need to be made [public-key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). That's done by way of [hybrid cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). Directly encrypting images with ECC cryptography would have terrible performance, thus is not worth serious consideration.
- There's no clear need to improve any of these algorithms in a way where machine learning seems to be necessary or even helpful.

In a quite different direction: Machine learning also has a poor track record at *attacking* modern cryptographic algorithms, but that idea may not be worthless. Perhaps machines one day will learn cryptanalysis.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/957 seems a decent example of ML in attacking PUFs, though those aren't what I'd generally classify as cryptography. And https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1235 tries to use it finding differentials in block ciphers, though it's not terribly good at it.

Comment: With regards to ML-aided attacks, this thread and the references cited therein seem worth mentioning: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72175/using-ai-to-perform-cryptanalysis .

Automated tools of any kind that can do interesting cryptanalysis could also potentially be very helpful in pushing the design of e.g. ultra lightweight ciphers further. I would therefore not be quite as pessimistic as you about machines maybe some day learning to design ciphers.