# The existing approaches based on machine learning for cryptography

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, quantum-cryptography, machine-learning

i'm working on a paper about Machine learning and Deep Learning and i'm wondring about the uses of this domain in cryptography!!
so what are these application of Ml that we use in cryptography and the tecniques for that !

Comment: Please do a little search `machine learning` in our site. [Any practical uses of machine learning for cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9751/18298), [Can neural cryptanalysis be applied to AES?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67402/18298)

Comment: it sounds too much like you are trying to get people to give help to write your paper--without focusing a vague question.